# How to Move Up Only the textfield in Flutter Without Shifting the Whole Screen?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Flutter app with an AppBar, an Image, a TextField, and two Buttons. When I open the keyboard to type, the whole screen moves up. I want the AppBar and other widgets to stay in place, and only the textfield should move up. How can I achieve this?

Here is a sample image for better understanding.

[image: sample screenshot]

I set 'resizeToAvoidBottomInset' as true, but the entire widgets at the bottom moves up.

Here is sample of my code

```
   Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          AppBar(),
          Positioned(
            top: pageHeight * 0.12, left: 0, right: 0,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
              child: ImageWidget(),
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(35),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 25),
                    child: PhoneNumField(
                      countryCode: 91,
                      controller: _phoneNumController,
                    )),
                  const SizedBox(height: 20),  
                  CommonButton(label: 'Login', onTap: (){})  
                  const SizedBox(height: 40,),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      SocialLoginButton(label: 'Google', icon: 'assets/icon/google.png', onTap: (){}),
                      const SizedBox(width: 20,),
                      SocialLoginButton(label: 'Facebook', icon: 'assets/icon/facebook.png', onTap: (){})
                    ],
                  ),
                  const SizedBox(height: 70,),
                  Text('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus eu condimentum purus. Suspendisse non erat tortor.',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 11,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.25),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: So you want to make the text field flying, detached from the login button when the keyboard is open?

Comment: Yes. I want the text field to move above the keyboard.